# How can i pass the formGroup of a child components to Parent Component

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have so many forms of different component's in my Page and one single clear button(from parent component) which basically just clears out all input fields of forms. I am stucking at how can i pass child component's FormGroup to parent component so that i can reset those forms from parent component.

Comment: Have you tried firing an event from the Parent Component which is listened in the child component and this event listener in the child component clears the form?

Answer (score 0):

1)You need EventEmitter, in your child component you can initialize your form group and send it to parent parent component.

In your child component:

```
export class TestComponent1Component implements OnInit {

  // Crete EventEmitter
  eventEmitter = new EventEmitter<FormGroup>();

  myFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      someControl: new FormControl("TestValue"),
    });

    this.eventEmitter.emit(this.myFormGroup);
  }

}
```

Then in your parent component Html:

```
<app-test-component1 (eventEmitter)="eventListener($event)"></app-test-component1>
```

And in your parent component ts file:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "AngularTestApp";

  private childFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  eventListener(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    this.childFormGroup = formGroup;
  }
}
```

2)Another option would be to use ViewChild

In your parent component ts set @ViewChild, notice that ViewChild is available after view has been initialized:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  title = "AngularTest";

  @ViewChild("childComponent", { static: false })
  testComponent1Component: TestComponent1Component;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.testComponent1Component.myFormGroup);
  }
}
```

In your parent html:

```
<app-test-component1 #childComponent></app-test-component1>
```

Comment: Both of these approach i have already tried. With ViewChild Approach it is not taking formgroup with component.

Comment: In ViewChild approach you set public myFormGroup: FormGroup in your child component and initialize the myFormGroup in ngOnInit(), then it should be available trough ViewChild reference in your parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, perhaps, pass the form groups to the children. You can still have each child be in control of the contents of each form group, but having them all part of a parent form, you get `form.reset` and `form.markAllAsTouched` from the parent form and `form.valid` for all the groups gets bubbled up to the parent.

From what I can tell, there are 3 ways to do this:

1. pass the form group as an input to the child
2. grab ControlContainer in the constructor
3. implement ControlValueAccessor

Stackblitz with side-by-side comparison:
https://angular-ivy-2ygm3a.stackblitz.io

## @Input()

parent component will pass a form group like:

```html
<input-party-form [form]="$any(form.controls['party'])"></input-party-form>
```

and the child component will fill it out on ngOnInit:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { PartyForm } from 'src/app/form-types';

interface InputPartyForm extends PartyForm {
    FormInput2: FormControl<string>,
}

@Component({
    selector: 'input-party-form[form]',
    templateUrl: './input-party-form.component.html',
})
export class InputPartyFormComponent implements OnInit  {
    @Input() public form: FormGroup<InputPartyForm>;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form.addControl("count", new FormControl(undefined,[]));
        this.form.addControl("FormInput2", new FormControl("",[]));
    }
}
```

This has some trouble when the parent form changes. As in you would need to check if the form group that you were passed already has the controls. Perhaps `@Input()` changes to `get/set`, or ngOnChanges, etc.

## ControlContainer

parent component will pass a form group like:

```html
    <control-container-party-form formGroupName="party">
```

and the component will handle fill it out similarly:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { PartyForm } from 'src/app/form-types';

interface ControlContainerPartyForm extends PartyForm {
    ControlContainerInput2: FormControl<string>,
}

@Component({
    selector: 'control-container-party-form',
    templateUrl: './control-container-party-form.component.html',
})
export class ControlContainerPartyFormComponent implements OnInit  {
    public form : FormGroup<ControlContainerPartyForm>;
    constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form = this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup<ControlContainerPartyForm>;
        this.form.addControl("count", new FormControl());
        this.form.addControl("ControlContainerInput2", new FormControl("",[]));
    }
}
```

## ControlValueAccessor

template is similar to the above:

```html
<control-value-accessor-party-form formControlName="party">
```

but the component typescript is more involved. You need to implement a few form methods. Mark as touched, and and form.valid didn't work for this one. I probably missed some . I also couldn't get typed forms to work nicely with it so they are all still `UntypedFormControl`:

```js
import { Component, forwardRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, UntypedFormControl, UntypedFormGroup, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'control-value-accessor-party-form',
    templateUrl: './control-value-accessor-party-form.component.html',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => ControlValueAccessorPartyFormComponent),
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class ControlValueAccessorPartyFormComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor  {
    public form: UntypedFormGroup = new UntypedFormGroup({});

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form.addControl("count", new UntypedFormControl("",[]));
        this.form.addControl("ControlValueAccessorInput2", new UntypedFormControl("",[]));
    }
    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        obj && this.form.setValue(obj, {emitEvent: false});
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
    }
    public onTouched: () => void = () => {};
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }
    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        isDisabled ? this.form.disable(): this.form.enable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**@ViewChild:**
you can use @ViewChild with the type of your component.
here is how:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-employee',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css'],
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(yourChildComponent) variableToAccessFormGroup: yourChildComponent;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     // Access your FormGroup from the yourChildComponent
     console.log(this.variableToAccessForm.yourFormGroupNameInYourChildComponent);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).